# How to echo the Firefox's option value with vimperator?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I want to know the Firefox's option value with echo command or other command and I can't find the anwser in vimperator's manual.
(I know that :set! can view the Firefox's option value, but I want use echo command)

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo options.getPref("your setting here")
```

For example

```
echo options.getPref("accessibility.accesskeycausesactivation")
```